# Javascript Object vs Map/Set key lookup performance

Tags: javascript, performance, dictionary, object, set

I was trying to explore how JavaScript `Object` performs in comparison to `Map` or `Set` for normal key accesses. I ran the below 3 codes on [JSBEN.CH](https://jsben.ch/q4RPK).

**Objects**

```
const object = {};

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    object[`key_${i}`] = 1;
}

let result = 0;
  
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    result += object[`key_${i}`];
}
```

**Maps**

```
const map = new Map();

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    map.set(`key_${i}`, 1);
}

let result = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    result += map.get(`key_${i}`);
}
```

**Sets**

```
const set = new Set();

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    set.add(`key_${i}`);
}

let result = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    result += set.has(`key_${i}`);
}
```

As you can check in the test link, `Map` and `Set` seem to perform almost similar however `Objects` are much slower every time. Can someone explain what could be the reason that `Objects` perform worse than `Map` or `Set` for basic key access operation?

**Edit 1**: Just setting keys on `Object` is [also slower](https://jsben.ch/al9ef) than `Map`/`Set`.

Comment: `set.add` only takes one argument.

Comment: Most engines have various representations for objects. It might take some time for the engine to find the right one ("to get hot").

Comment: The real question is whether the JSBENC is reliable. Have you tried any other performance testers besides JSBENC?

Comment: @JonasWilms my bad ... updated the code and link

Comment: @EdisonPebojot Can you name any other testers that you think is reliable? Jsperf is not working anymore and i'm really new to performance testing so don't know how to do this manually

Comment: you are not adding the `set` values correctly. `result += set.has(\`key_${i}\`) ? i : 0;`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn The second answer talks about performance but there is no clear answer there. I want to know whether we have a definite answer to this? Also more important do we know WHY maps are performing better?

Comment: The second answer posts a link to an article by 1 of the authors of the v8 javascript engine. In short: "This is because Javascript engines compile objects down to C++ classes in the background"

Comment: @dehart But that would assert that `objects` perform better which is not so in above tests

Comment: They answer the question by saying that a `Map` loops over the values in order that they were added whereas an object does not. See [Map Description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#description) and [Map vs Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps)

Comment: Guessing here: There keys are not looked up in the order of insertion of keys. And object lookup has to convert the key to string before comparing. And Map and sets just search in the key-value collection while Object checks with the prototype if a key is not found?

Comment: So if someone wants to stop guessing, one can run `node --allow-natives-syntax` and then add a `%DebugPrint(object)` to the loop. You'll see that the internal representation changes multiple times

Comment: @D_S_X They are performing better simply because they were optimised for that task, whereas objects are optimised for static lookups on non-changing shapes (while they also support dynamic lookup, it's not their main use case).

Answer (score 33):

Looking at relative numbers only is always dangerous, here are some absolute numbers, run on NodeJS v14.14.0 on an Intel 8350U:

| Iterations | Object write | Object read | Map write | Map read |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 0ms | 0ms | 0ms | 0ms |
| 1.000 | 3ms | 1ms | 0ms | 0ms |
| 10,000 | 7ms | 4ms | 8ms | 1ms |
| 1.000.000 | 1222ms | 527ms | 632ms | 542ms |

So as one can see, for 10.000 iterations the difference between objects and maps is 1 millisecond in the run above, and as that is the accuracy of the time measurement, we can't really derive any conclusion from that test. The results are absolutely random.

For 1 Million iterations one can see a clear advantage of Map writes over Object writes, the read performance is very similar. Now if we look at absolute numbers, this is still *one million writes / s*. So although object writes are a lot slower, this will unlikely be the bottleneck of your application.

For an accurate explanation, one would have to analyze all the steps the engine performs. For that you can run `node --print-code` and analyze the bytecode that gets run. I don't have the time for that, though here are some observations:

1. If the object gets constructed with `Object.create(null)` (having no prototype) the performance is about the same, so prototype lookup does not influence performance at all.
2. After the 20th iteration, V8 chooses the internal representation `dictionary_map` for `object`, so this is basically one hash map competing with another hashmap (one can run `node --allow-natives-syntax` and then use `%DebugPrint(object)` to get the internal representation).

For reference, here is the code used to run the benchmark:

```js
function benchmark(TIMES) {  
  console.log("BENCHMARK ", TIMES);

  const object = Object.create(null);

    let start = Date.now();
    for (let i = 0; i < TIMES; ++i) {
        object[`key_${i}`] = 1;
    }

    console.log("Object write took", Date.now() - start);
    start = Date.now();

    let result = 0;
  
    for (let i = 0; i < TIMES; ++i) {
      result += object[`key_${i}`];
    }

    console.log("Object read took", Date.now() - start);
    start = Date.now();

  


  const map = new Map();
  
  for (let i = 0; i < TIMES; ++i) {
    map.set(`key_${i}`, 1);
  }
  
  console.log("Map write took", Date.now() - start);
  start = Date.now();

  result = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < TIMES; ++i) {
    result += map.get(`key_${i}`);
  }

  console.log("Map read took", Date.now() - start);

}

benchmark(100);
benchmark(1_000);
benchmark(10_000);
benchmark(1_000_000);
```

To sum up:

- Use Maps for dictionaries with lots of different, changing keys as they are slightly better than objects internally represented as hash table
- Use Objects for - well - objects. If you have a low number of keys and frequently access those, Objects are way faster (as the engine can use inline caching, hidden classes with fixed memory layout etc.)

Comment: Thanks for putting all these test cases together. I would accept this answer but this still doesn't explain the why (although it does rule out the fact that prototype chaining maybe causing this which is good). Key take away up until now is that for cases involving frequent addition and removal `maps` will perform better as they are somehow internally optimised for it.

Comment: @D_S_X well, the answer is somewhere [in here](https://github.com/v8/v8) (and the same applies to other engines). You could probably spend some time digging through the sourcecode and somewhen find the "why", though that's a very time intensive process (and I don't have time for that). You could ask a [tag:v8] specific question and hope that a maintainer sees your question, though they are also usually not giving concrete answers as the implementations are frequently changing and they won't answer that question again and again ...